# Getting vue to show only class with a specific value in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have this code and I'm trying to only display those classes that has a certain value when clicked. For example if I click the button complete then only those with "complete" and if it is "incomplete" then only show the incomplete ones. I'm not sure on how to proceed.

Here is my vuejs code

```
    <template>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item" @click="sortComplete">
                                Completed
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item" @click="sortPending">
                                Not Complete
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-sm mt-2">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th> </th>
                                </tr>

                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                                <tr v-for="item in items" :class="item.value">
                                    <td>
                                       {{ item.title }} 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            data: function() {
                return {
                    items: [
                        {title: 'Task 1', value: "incomplete"},
                        {title: 'Task 2', value: "Completed"},
                        {title: 'Task 3', value: "Completed"},
                        {title: 'Task 4', value: "incomplete"}
                    ]
                }


            },

            methods: {
                sortComplete: function(){

                },

                sortPending: function(){

                }
            }
        }
    </script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// ignore the following two lines, they just disable warnings in "Run code snippet"
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: function() {
    return {
      filter: 'all',
      items: [{
          title: 'Task 1',
          value: "incomplete"
        },
        {
          title: 'Task 2',
          value: "complete"
        },
        {
          title: 'Task 3',
          value: "complete"
        },
        {
          title: 'Task 4',
          value: "incomplete"
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      if (this.filter === 'all') return this.items;
      else return this.items.filter(item => item.value === this.filter);
    }
  },

  methods: {
    setFilter: function(filter) {
      this.filter = filter;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" @click="setFilter('complete')">Completed</li>
          <li class="list-group-item" @click="setFilter('incomplete')">Not Complete</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-9">
        <table class="table table-striped table-sm mt-2">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th> </th>
            </tr>

          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="item in filteredItems" :class="filteredItems.value">
              <td>
                {{ item.title }}
              </td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Firstly, would recommend not using mixed casing in your naming convention. In the sense that "Completed" is capitalised whereas "incomplete" isn't.

Stick to one, just makes it easier in terms of readability and you run into fewer unnecessary issues.

```
data: function() {
  return {
    filter: 'all',
    items: [
      {title: 'Task 1', value: "incomplete"},
      {title: 'Task 2', value: "complete"},
      {title: 'Task 3', value: "complete"},
      {title: 'Task 4', value: "incomplete"}
    ]
  }
},
```

For your specific functionality, you're better of using `computed` properties to iterate over a filtered list, will be something like this,

```
<tr v-for="item in filteredItems" :class="filteredItems.value">
  <td>
    {{ item.title }} 
  </td>
</tr>
```

And you could use computed props like so,

```
computed: {
  filteredItems() {
    if (this.filter === 'all') return this.items;
    else return this.items.filter(item => item.value === this.filter);
  }
}
```

And your triggers would change to,

```
<li class="list-group-item" @click="sortComplete('complete')">Completed</li>
<li class="list-group-item" @click="sortPending('incomplete')">Not Complete</li>
```